# OpenStreenMap API not Showing distance

Tags: openstreetmap

This is the API Endpoint was working a day ago. It was fine and suddenly it stop working.

It's not showing distance calculation.

https://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/51.50643,-0.12719;52.92342,-1.48443

Response

```json
{
    "code": "Ok",
    "routes": [
        {
            "geometry": "xevUqb}oI??",
            "legs": [
                {
                    "steps": [],
                    "summary": "",
                    "weight": 0,
                    "duration": 0,
                    "distance": 0
                }
            ],
            "weight_name": "routability",
            "weight": 0,
            "duration": 0,
            "distance": 0
        }
    ],
    "waypoints": [
        {
            "hint": "g71QhMPap4QAAAAAcgAAAAAAAABlAAAAAAAAAMcx_kEAAAAAqSzgQQAAAAByAAAAAAAAAGUAAACIJwKAN1pKA7svx__-7BEDKg_-_wAAvwhwyHH8",
            "distance": 572182.973187538,
            "name": "",
            "location": [
                55.204407,
                -3.723333
            ]
        },
        {
            "hint": "g71QhMPap4QAAAAAcgAAAAAAAABlAAAAAAAAAMcx_kEAAAAAqSzgQQAAAAByAAAAAAAAAGUAAACIJwKAN1pKA7svx_8cjCcDclnp_wAAvwhwyHH8",
            "distance": 354444.952421905,
            "name": "",
            "location": [
                55.204407,
                -3.723333
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```